# How to know when the app is published in Google PlayStore beta Channel?

Tags: android, google-play

This is been in my mind for several days now, I did not have this dependency before. But following has happened.

In my app I have coded to tell the user that a new version is available and ask him to update if he wants. And the catch is I do not know when the app update is available.

So my question is, is there any means to know when the app is published in the beta channel? And I really think there is something wrong with pushing beta updates(While creating testers group on Google Groups not on Google+)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to send a push notification to your users, when you update your app on play store. On the basis of the push notification, you can either show it in the notification bar or you can set some preferences of your app, which can be used later to notify the user that an update is available.

Comment: yeah Eric, but my question was that how do I know that app has been published. Because it will take some time to publish after we upload the apk right?